# Does the Dark Arts Archlich warlock patrons's Arcane Invisibility activate every time you cast a level 1+ spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, warlock

The Dark Arts Archlich Patron for Warlock says that:

> #### Arcane Invisibility
>
> At 1st level, **when you expend a spell slot of 1st level or higher**,
>       you and all that you are wearing or carrying becomes invisible
>       until the start of your next turn, or until you attack or cast a spell.

But Warlock Spellcasting says expending a spell slot like that happens any time you cast a level 1 or higher spell (PHB):

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have.  The table also shows what the level of those slots is; all of your spell slots are the same level. **To cast one of your warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a spell slot.**

Does this mean that the *Arcane Invisibility* power triggers whenever the PC casts any spell of level 1 or higher, since that **expends** a level 1 or higher spell slot?  (Any spell other than a cantrip).

In other words, if the PC casts a level 1 spell such as *hex*, does the PC become invisible?

For Clarity on Material:

[Source](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-g9vLTX0eHKUWgxclhVU0c4dEE/view)

Comment: I have been trying to track down the source of this ability and have been unable to find it. As far as I can tell it is not from Unearthed Arcana, but I may be overlooking something obvious. Can you provide a link to the source you're getting this from?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-g9vLTX0eHKUWgxclhVU0c4dEE/view

Comment: Our DM has put this in our dropbox folder under unearthed arcana, it's really difficult to tell the difference, but it looks like its not official material.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Your interpretation is correct (mostly)**

Indeed, casting a spell usually means expending a spell slot.

The distinction is made because there are ways to cast spells without expending a spell slot which would not trigger the Arcane Invisibility feature, for example (this is not a comprehensive list):

- Casting a cantrip (0-level spell)
- Casting a spell from a scroll, wand, or a ring of spell storing.
- Casting a spell using a racial or class feature that does not expend a spell slot (for example, some results of a sorcerer's Wild Magic, the Tiefling's Hellish Rebuke or the Drow's Faerie FIre)

Furthermore, there are ways to expend spell slots without casting a spell, such as the paladin smite feature, which do trigger Arcane Invisibility.

Comment: A very relevant example of spellcasting without expending a spell slot would be the Mystic Arcanum warlock class feature, as well as the few warlock Eldritch Invocations that allow you to freely cast certain spells without expending a slot.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, you alredy quoted pretty much everything that was needed to answer your question.

The arcane invisibility will trigger whenever you cast a spell that isn't a cantrip (level 0 spell).

Comment: This answer is simply outright wrong. It will not trigger on casting a Mystic Arcanum (Warlock level 6-9) spell, as these do *not* use spell slots. The trigger is not a spell being cast, but rather a slot being used. Also, see invocations for casting a spell without use of a spell slot.

Comment: Likewise, rituals (which the warlock can gain access to through the pact of the Tome and the right invocation) don't involve using a spell slot.